# What is the best way to constantly switch between Mac and PC?

Tags: mac, desktop-computer, boot-camp, external-display, kvm-switch

I have a need to be using my iMac but also a PC during separate times of the day. This switch needs to happen every day, for the next year.

I currently have a 5k iMac. I use windows by using bootcamp right now. I have considered the following options

1. VM is not an option as my applications are graphic intensive.
2. Remote desktop is a bit too much latency for my application
3. A KVM switch wouldn't work in this case since the iMac has the display and computer combined.

Rebooting back and forth each day is quite time consuming.

I could just purchase a PC but I don't have enough real estate on my desk to have two displays.

What is a better configuration here that would allow me to constantly switch between mac and PC?

Comment: You've listed all the options; none are ideal. I don't think we can decide for you. I'd go with a VM & put up with slower graphics in exchange for faster switching. Personally I use Mac Pros & hardware WinPCs with separate displays & i can either switch which machine is viewed on the displays or if I want both at once, I use RDP. You're a bit more stuck with an iMac. BTW, there's a trick if your Win app needs the hardware GPU - start the app locally, then remote into it. It will use the hardware GPU instead of moaning it only has a software GPU over RDP.

Comment: @Tetsujin I guess I was see if there is some configuration I was not aware of. Like if there is some magic way of showing the PC's display output inside macOS but not over the network

Comment: This is the main reason why I won't buy an iMac, although at the moment I don't mind at all with my M1 Mac mini, which does share a keyboard, mouse, and monitor with my work PC.  Beyond completely changing your hardware set up, I would go with a remote desktop, which shouldn't be too bad over a local network.

Comment: @jimtut I dont mind changing my hardware setup but there isn't even a headless mac that has decent graphic capability (that is reasonably priced)

Comment: We've just bought an M1 iMac for my partner. She's a 'one compy/one screen' kinda gal;) Everything else here is still old cheesegrater Mac Pros - 64GB RAM, many [2k & 4k] screens, many drives, uprated graphics [though perhaps slow by modern standards, HD 7950s] Sure, I'd love one of the new Mac Pros, but I also need a new car;)